# Find the probability (Conditional and total probability needed).

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> In the first box you have 8 white balls and 4 black balls, in the second box you have 5 white balls and 7 black balls, in the third box you have 6 white and 6 black balls and in the fourth box you have 3 white balls and 9 black balls. Without looking at we chose a box and take 2 balls from the chosen box. Find the probability:
>
> - a) Chosen balls are white,
> - b)chosen balls are different colors ,
> - c) chosen balls are black.

I started (a) by writing the hypotheses H1: balls are chosen from the first box, H2: From the second box, H3: From the third box and H4: From the fourth box, A and the Event A: Chosen balls are white. Now my question for (a) is do I have to use Total Probability Formula if yes then P(hypotheses) is it going to be the same for all hypotheses 1/4,  what is going to be conditional probability :PH1(A).
If someone can answer is it enough to do the (a) cuz (c) is similar, and please help with (b) cuz I don't even know how to start, actually I'm not very sure. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your questions a), b) and c) there is not any conditional probability requested.

To solve the posted questions, as you mentioned, Total probability theorem is enough

example

a)

Two white balls (without replacement, I suppose) are drawn

$$\mathbb{P}[WW]=\frac{1}{4}\Bigg[\frac{8\cdot7}{12\cdot11}+\frac{5\cdot4}{12\cdot11}+\frac{6\cdot5}{12\cdot11}+\frac{3\cdot2}{12\cdot11}\Bigg]$$

et cetera et cetera